# http request using json-pointer slack view.publish JSON-encoded string

Tags: api, http, postman

Im trying to make this api POST request to [view.publish](https://api.slack.com/methods/views.publish) endpoint on slack api

As the documentation explains, im using the token and user_id in params, but i dont know what do i need to do with the view param

[image]

i set "application/json;charset=UTF-8"  as content-type in the headers and on the body the JSON of the payload i want to publish:

```
{
    "blocks": [
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": "This is a section block with a button."
            },
            "accessory": {
                "type": "button",
                "text": {
                    "type": "plain_text",
                    "text": "Click Me",
                    "emoji": true
                },
                "value": "click_me_123",
                "url": "http://scoreboard-azureslackbot-salvosoftware.s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/",
                "action_id": "button-action"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This error is displayed when i make that api call:

```
{
    "ok": false,
    "error": "invalid_arguments",
    "response_metadata": {
        "messages": [
            "[ERROR] failed to match all allowed schemas [json-pointer:/view]",
            "[ERROR] must provide an object [json-pointer:/view]",
            "[ERROR] must provide an object [json-pointer:/view]"
        ]
    }
}
```

Documentation says that view must be a JSON-encoded string

[image]

Also this warning is displayed in the body tab:

[image]

Comment: remove the content hehader you add manually , postman adds it automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is from Aubrey, support team in slack.

No params needed.
In the Authorization tab you need beared authorization.

[image]

On the body you need to set is as raw -> JSON and this would be your JSON:

```
{
    "user_id": {{YOUR_USER_ID}},
    "view": {
        "type": "home",
    "blocks": [
        {
            {{YOUR_PAYLOAD}}
        }
    ] 
    }
}
```

It helped me basing on this CURL command

```
curl -L -X POST 'https://slack.com/api/views.publish' \
-H 'Content-type: application/json' \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer {{YOUR TOKEN}}' \
--data-raw '{
    "user_id": {{YOUR USER ID}},
    "view": {
        "type": "home",
    "blocks": [{
            {{YOUR PAYLOAD}}
        }] 
    }
}'
```